# inserting data in database table in one to many relationship in code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, data-annotations, one-to-many

I am using Code First Approach with Mvc4.For authentication and authorization, simple membership is being used.
My UserProfile class have these fields where a user can have multiple posts and comments.

```
  [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.PostComments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string AvatarExt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and my Post class is something like this.here i have configured one to many relationship between userprofile class and Post class.

```
   public class Post
  {
    public Post()
    {
        this.PostComments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int PostedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller's action method for adding posts to the post table in the database.

```
   public HttpResponseMessage PostPost(Post post)
    {
        post.PostedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        post.PostedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
       // post.UserProfile.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedBy");
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedDate");
      //  ModelState.Remove("post.UserProfile.UserId");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var usr = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == post.PostedBy);
            var ret = new
            {
                Message = post.Message,
                PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                PostedByName = usr.UserName,
                PostedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : post.PostedBy + "." + post.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                PostId = post.PostId
            };
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, ret);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = post.PostId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

when i tried to debug this action method, i found out that it is passing null at this line---

```
  PostedByName = usr.UserName
```

what should i do to pass current loggedIn userName to the database.
One more information i want to share is--
**In Sql Server, it is creating 5 columns----
PostId(which is primary key),
Message,PostedBy(int),PostedDate, UserProfile_UserId(Foreign key column).
Now, everything is working fine but in UserProfile_UserId column, it is storing null.**
I know it should not be null but how.
What i am missing.what should i do.There was slight change in this code using dbFirst approach, and that code is working fine.

To get post on the view page, action method is----

```
    public dynamic GetPosts()
    {

        var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = post.Message,
                       PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                       PostedByName = post.UserProfile.UserName,
                       PostedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.UserProfile.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : post.PostedBy + "." + post.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                       PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                       PostId = post.PostId,
                       PostComments = from comment in post.PostComments.ToList()
                                      orderby comment.CommentedDate
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          CommentedBy = comment.CommentedBy,
                                          CommentedByName = comment.UserProfile.UserName,
                                          CommentedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment.UserProfile.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : comment.CommentedBy + "." + comment.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                                          CommentedDate = comment.CommentedDate,
                                          CommentId = comment.CommentId,
                                          Message = comment.Message,
                                          PostId = comment.PostId

                                      }
                   }).AsEnumerable();
        return ret;
    }
```

this is the action method where i want to show post and comment with their UserName.here, PostedByName is returning null.

Comment: You don't have an `int UserProfile_UserId` property in your model (how can you set it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so should i manually define fk field and return back value manually for that column to store in database or entity framework will insert that value automatically

Comment: If I understand correctly, `PostedBy` is the same as `UserProfile_UserId`? Do you need both?

Comment: yupp, u r right i think postedBy is same as UserProfile_UserId.But, i am confused whether there should be Both column or not. I have edited my question and included Get method for post also.It gives System.NullReferenceException. And in Get Method for post too, it returns  null at PostedByName property when i debug it. @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke u can have a look at this code.It's in DbFirst Approach.I have coverted those to code first https://github.com/techbrij/fb-wall-post

Comment: You only need one. I'm not sure from your last comment if your using DbFirst or CodeFirst, but the `PostedBy` should be deleted in the db. In the view you could keep `PostedBy` but decorate it with `[Column(Name="UserProfile_UserId")]` or replace it with `int UserProfile_UserId`

Comment: @StephenMuecke As u said, i deleted postedBy from database and decorated PostedBy with [Column(Name="UserProfile_UserId")]. It just created new column with name UserProfile_UserId and my Foreign key name is now changed to UserProfile_UserId1 and it's still store null value

Comment: @StephenMuecke plzz help me out i am using code first i have provided u with the link from where i was following